# Using Single Sign-On and the usage of password managers is discouraged. Whay are alternatives for storing tokens for example?

Tags: passwords, password-management

What are the alternatives of storing tokens when password managers are discouraged?

Some of the ideas that come to my mind are storing in a text file and encrypting with GnuPG but that's asks for extra password.

**Edit**
Security team discourages the usage of the password manager. In the context of a company policy.
I agree the question is vague but that's the limited information I can offer.

Comment: Can you give us some context for this question?

Comment: Who discourages SSO and/or password managers? In what context and with what justification?

Comment: "storing in a text file and encrypting": that's a password manager.

Comment: "Discouraged" does not mean "prohibited". If you're going to store passwords, there is no safer digital solution than a proper password manager. SSO is a server-side decision. If it's deemed insecure, 2FA can help, as can skipping SSO for more sensitive portals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the alternatives of storing tokens when password managers are discouraged?

Use a password manager. Ignore the advice.

> Some of the ideas that come to my mind are storing in a text file and encrypting with GnuPG but that's asks for extra password.

That's effectively a very crude password manager that risks leaving clear text files behind.